Unable to Establish WebSocket Connection to Spring Boot Server (Error: 400 Bad Request)
Details of the problem:
I'm encountering an issue while attempting to connect to a WebSocket server hosted at ws://localhost:8080/ws. The error message I receive is as follows:
*Could not connect to ws://localhost:8080/ws
16:34:08
Error: Unexpected server response: 400
*
Here are the handshake details:
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/ws
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 400
My Spring Boot application is running on port 8080, while the client side is on port 3000.
WebSocket Configuration:
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic"); 
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").withSockJS();
    }

}

Cors Configuration:

@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS") 
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .exposedHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .maxAge(3600);
    }
}

I've tried various WebSocket clients to connect to the server, including wscat, browser-based WebSocket clients, and others, but all attempts resulted in the same error. I've verified that the server is running, and the WebSocket endpoint is correctly configured in the Spring Boot application. Despite this, I'm unable to establish a successful connection.

Is there any error in server logs?

no errors, these are some logs: WebSocketHandlerMapping: Mapped to org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.SockJsHttpRequestHandler@6c61260b
SockJsService: Processing transport request: GET http://localhost:8080/ws
WebSocketMessageBrokerStats: WebSocketSession[0 current WS(0)-HttpStream(0)-HttpPoll(0), 0 total, 0 closed abnormally (0 connect failure, 0 send limit, 0 transport error)]

Two things  I can suggest. 1. Check response body on client, it may contain some clues. 2. Try to debug server-side and catch any exceptions.
